# Delegation vs exposing properties

Tags: c#, design-patterns

i was looking at facade-like delegation in classes, for example let's suppose that you got the Equipment class ( with Equip() and UnEquip()  methods), and then you have a Player class which has a reference to the Equipment.

The way i would implement the Player class is to have some public methods like EquipItem and UnEquipItem, and those methods will delegate the tasks to the Equipment class. Now if the player also has another class that does stuff, like movement, then i would put again some public methods on the Player class that delegates to the Movement class, in a facade-like way. Now one of the disadvantages of the facade pattern is the growing interface the more classes or systems it handles. And let's suppose that i know that in the future, the Player class will have alot more functionality.

I don't know if this is the correct approach, nonetheless i was thinking if it would be possible to expose the Equipment and Movement references as properties, like so:

```
Class Player
{
     public Equipment equipment { get; set; }
     public Movement movement { get; set; }
}
```

Now, i know that exposing the object's state is bad, but this way you have a better control of the growing interface of the class, and have more focused methods on the Player class. So instead of:

```
player.Equip();
```

you can do

```
player.equipment.Equip();
```

Sooo finally, my question would be what is the best approach in this scenario, or maybe i got something wrong ?. Thanks

PS: the example is from a game area, but the solution doesn't have to be necessarily applicable to games, i just thought it was simple to understand.

Comment: Note that properties don't technically expose state, they are just methods (like getX/setX methods in other languages).

Comment: the class is not `static` so where are you actuall instantiating an instance of the `Player` Class..? read up on [C# Basics Tutorials](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_classes.htm)

Comment: Personally, i'd go about this in a totally different approach. I wouldn't have `Movement` as part of the players properties, but perhaps have a `Game` class, which would be responsible for the movement of players in the game.

Comment: @MathodMan Oh sorry, the class isn't static just for demostration purposes, i just wanted to express the idea with as little code as possible so it was easier to understand

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov you are right, but note that i wasn't expecting a correct solution on the game thing, what i tried to convery was what would you do in a situation where your public interface would grow quit a bit. And how would you go about accesing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate approach would be to develop a set of command actions that can be applied to the player which manipulate the state.  While the command objects would have extended access to the player, the outer API would keep the implementation details as a black box.

As an example:

```
public abstract class Action 
{
   public abstract void ActOn(Player player);
}

public class EquipAction : Action 
{
    private Item item;
    public EquipCommand(Item item) {
      this.item = item;
    }

    public void ActOn(Player player) {
       player.Equipment.Add(item);
    }
} 

public interface IPlayer
{
    void PerformAction(Action action);
}

public class EquipmentSet
{
    public List<Item> Items { get; private set;}
} 

public class EquipmentManager
{
    public Add(Item item) {
    }

    public List<Item> Items { get; }
}

public class Player : IPlayer
{
    public EquipmentManager manager;

    public PerformAction(Action action) {
       action.ActOn(this);
    }

    public List<Items> Equipment {
       return manager.Items;
    }
}
```

Now obviously, there's a lot more that should be done to make this fully capable to do what you want, but the idea would be to limit your public interface to player to the structure that you want to expose (e.g. attributes, equipment, status, .etc) and delegate all the verbs to actions.

Under the covers, the actual functionality of a Player could be broken up into as many components as would make sense to limit the size of each individual components.

Comment: interesting, so instead of the objects acting directly on the player, you access it inderectly throught commands ( and you still decided to expose the property to access the class instance). The only thing that worries me is that this way you would have to make one class per different command ( for example one for Equip() and one or Unequip(), is that correct ? ). So would this be a problem escalating to a lot of commands ? would it be acceptable to manage a mid-large quantity?

Comment: While you could have a large number of commands in the system, if you take the time to group them logically it will be easier to keep track of the individual commands than a large API on one object.  Additionally, with the right test strategy, each command can be tested independently which will make it easier to keep your system running correctly with fewer side effects.